# Comparing string to array - React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, string, compare

```
let category = "design" //This place is changing, like art, design, photo

let filtered = data.filter((item) => category === item.category_name)`
```

category contains a string. item.category_name is an array.

What I want to do is a filtering event. but an item can have multiple categories.

For example, the category of the 3rd item is as follows :

"category_name" : [ "design", "art" ],

How can I get the 3rd item to be selected when the category variable is art or design?

how can i compare array with a string

Comment: Question is not clear can you please add more clarity to it ?

Comment: "when the category variable is both art and design" – what does `category` look like when it has both of these values? Is it still a string or is `category` now an array?

Comment: @DipanSharma I fixed the mistakes in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [include](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method, it works for strings and arrays.

```js
let filtered = data.filter((item) => item.category_name.includes(category))
```

so `"design".includes("design")` and `["design", "art"].includes("design")` will both return true

However, it would be best if you turned item.categoryName into an array, for consistency. Items with one category could have an array with only one item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'some' method which iterates over the array and returns true as soon as the condition is met:

```
let filtered = data.filter((item) => item.category_name.some((subItem) => subItem === category));
```